# Menu doesn't show right in Internet Explorer (Latest Version)

Tags: menu

I would appreciate if someone could help me here. The menu on my website https://sssextreme.com/ does not show correctly in IE but works fine in chrome and firefox.

My stylehseet is https://sssextreme.com/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djHK5.jpg)

Comment: i think there is a cookie problem. . in shopping cart page getting the same problem in ur site i tried in chrome

Comment: u gave padding left 1% in .page-header-container (style.css). . change that to 0% it is clear. . try this

Comment: thanks for helping, unfortunately that didn't seem to work for me

Comment: u just absorb the error while page loading in chrome or firefox. .the error will be in chrome also while loading but after completing the full load the error will clear. . so mostly this is a cookie problem.. .flush the cookie in backend and try